# Firebase topic expiry

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there a way to add an expiry time for the Firebase topic subscription.

I would like the subscription to a topic to be cleared at the end of every week or month.

Apart from manually calling unsubscribe, is there any method for me to specify an expiry time for the topic subscription while making the subscription?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebase Cloud Messaging topics don't auto-expire. Just like you explicitly make a call to subscribe a user/token to a topic, you will have to make an explicit call to unsubscribe them from that topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage it on the serverside, and unsubscribe registration IDs of the phones, where the registration expired.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/manage-topics